# Rails - ActiveAdmin and Papertrail - a DRY approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, paper-trail-gem

I have lot of Models where I use PaperTrail, like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

In the ActiveAdmin model's file I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  ...

  # versioning part
  action_item :history, only: :show do
    link_to('History', history_backend_user_path(user), method: :get)
  end

  sidebar :versionate, :partial => "layouts/version", :only => :show

  member_action :history do
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @versions = @user.versions.reorder(created_at: :desc)
    render "layouts/history"
  end
end
```

I have to repeat this lines for *every model* and I'm wondering how I could dry it up.

Comment: BTW have you looked at the [auditing plugins](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up with the following solution *which is working* (note also that all the references to `User` resource have been generalized):

```
# app/admin-shared/active_admin_loggable.rb

module ActiveAdminLoggable
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      action_item :history, only: :show do
        link_to('History',
                eval("history_backend_#{resource.class.to_s.downcase}_path(#{resource.class.to_s.downcase})"),
                method: :get
        )
      end

      sidebar :versionate, :partial => "layouts/version", :only => :show

      member_action :history do
        @this_resource = eval("resource.class").find(params[:id])
        @versions = @this_resource.versions.reorder(created_at: :desc)
        render "layouts/history"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and:

```
# app/admin/user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  extend ActiveAdminLoggable
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the common code into a concern.  You can then use ActiveAdmin's `include` method to incorporate the common code into your resources.

Here is the module which should contain your common code:

```
# app/admin/concerns/versionable.rb
module Versionable
  def self.included(dsl)
    dsl.action_item :history, only: :show do
      link_to 'History', dsl.history_backend_user_path(user), method: :get
    end

    dsl.sidebar :versionate, :partial => "layouts/version", :only => :show

    dsl.member_action :history do
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @versions = @user.versions.reorder(created_at: :desc)
      render "layouts/history"
    end
  end
end
```

You can then include this module in your ActiveAdmin resources.  For example:

```
# app/admin/user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  include Versionable
  ...
end
```

This is based on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789006/using-activeadmins-dsl-with-shared-module-includes).  It has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally used the code that I show in my answer, which I personally tested and it's working :)